# Can someone help me how can i crop image by dragging with fingers in android?

Tags: java, android, image

I successfully loaded image from gallery into my application layout but after that i need to crop image using fingers by dragging a rectangle in and out.I stuck here can someone help me how can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please provide a code sample where you stuck.

Comment: I dont have a code after loading image. I want to know what attributes from android library shall i use to achieve this. Is there any inbuilt functions that can achieve this task?

Comment: Here is the complete sample code to help you to crop image- https://github.com/lorensiuswlt/AndroidImageCrop

Comment: use this link..http://choiboijames.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-image-cropping-example.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I branched the code from the SoundCloud implementation (which was originally branched from the open source Android camera app) on GitHub, but it looks like there was a library released in August last year that we could use.

Link to it here
[http://www.androidviews.net/2013/08/cropper/][1]

Comment: Thank you for link but it is broken please can you resend it